# Replace text inside Wicket AjaxLink

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I have created a new AjaxLink in my .java file

```
add(new AjaxLink("link"){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;                                                                                                       

@Override                                                                                                                                              
public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {                                                                                                        
target.appendJavascript("window.open('http://www.cnn.com/2011/WORLD/africa/02/23/libya.protests/index.html?hpt="+T1+"')");              
}                                                                                                                                                      
});
```

And added it to my .html file

```
<a href="#" wicket:id="link">TEXT TO REPLACE</a>
```

The url is just an example but T1 is dynamic and I get that from my .java file. I would like the  "TEXT TO REPLACE" to equal the T1 string but I don't know how to do this. I have tried creating a Label and adding it like

```
<a href="#" wicket:id="link"><span wicket:id="linkLbl"></span></a>
```

but that gives an error.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: @user561793, so did you get it working? Be sure to accept the most helpful answer (green tickmark), or leave a comment if something's unclear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Label` is the right direction, but you have to make sure that you add the label in the java code as well, it should be a child component of your ajax link.

(On a sidenote: you might want to consider using `<wicket:container>` instead of `<span>`. In this case it doesn't matter much, but there are cases where an extra `<span>` tag would make your HTML invalid.)

Comment: That worked. Thank you. I didn't have the label declared as a child component of the AjaxLink but once I fixed that it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

a) Use a common Model for both Link and Label, b) don't forget to update the link

```
IModel<String> model = // get model data from somewhere

add(new AjaxLink("link"){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;                                                                                                       

@Override                                                                                                                                              
public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
target.addComponent(this); // update the link component
target.appendJavascript("window.open('http://www.cnn.com/2011/WORLD/africa/02/23"
  + "/libya.protests/index.html?hpt="+model.getObject()
     /* you probably want to encode this first */+"')");              
}                                                                                                                                                      
}).setOutputMarkupId().add(new Label("label",model));
```

Comment: Why would you want to update the link component when it's clicked?

Comment: Hmm, there's no `appendComponent` method in [AjaxRequestTarget](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxRequestTarget.html)

Comment: @Jonik addComponent(), sorry, was in a hurry